# How to get the address of the element which is pushed back in the list, In constant time,in c++ stl?

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
list<int> l;
list<int>::iterator lastElement;
lastElement=l.end()
l.push_back(10);
cout<<"Address of the element 10 in the list is"<<&lastElement<<endl;
```

Is the above way the correct way to get the address of the last element of a list in constant time. I know there are many other methods but I want a method that gives the address in constant time.

Comment: No. `end()` is one past the last, not the last. `&lastElement` is the address of the iterator, not what you added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the address of the element which is pushed back in the list, In constant time,in c++ stl?

After pushing the element, use `std::list::back` to get reference to the element. Then use the operator & to get the address of the element (or use `std::addressof` if the operator is overloaded, which is unusual).

> Is the above way the correct way to get the address of the last element of a list

No. There are several problems:

- `std::list:end` returns an iterator to the element past the end of the list; not an iterator to the last element.
- You take the iterator before pushing an element into the list. The iterator cannot possibly be to an element that you later push to the list.
- You apply operator & on the iterator. The result is the address of the iterator; not the address of the element that the iterator points to.